# ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib' -- Using Anaconda tensorflow environment

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow, importerror, conda

I'm just trying to learn Tensorflow, but am totally new to Python, so I'm using Anaconda
I created a conda environment:

```
$ conda create −n tensorflow python =3.5
```

Of course I activated my conda environment

```
$ source activate tensorflow
```

Then I played a bit around in Spyder, tried to plot a MNIST-digit (copy-paste code from my tutor which is tested several times), it includes of course

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
[...]
plt.plot(number)
```

but executing the Python file with bash gives me:

```
(tensorflow) leon@leon-linux:~/ANNsCourse/Session1$ python helloWorld.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloWorld.py", line 10, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I'm quite confused right now, as the `(tensorflow)` in the bash obviously denotes that my conda tensorflow environment works (at least from my understanding). Also, from what I understood, conda should have matplotlib built in, right? And it should also load this in my conda tensorflow environment, right? This is what my tutor's slide said

> There is no need to install further packages like numpy or matplotlib, since Anaconda contains current versions of them already.'

and also what I was able to take from everything I Googled and StackOverflowed. Neither Googling nor StackOverflowing gave me any good answer (might also just be because I don't understand enough yet).

My best guess would be that I still have to include matplotlib into my tensorflow conda environment, but this would be contradicting both my tutor & Google, while I also would not know how to do this.

edit: `conda list` gave me that matplotlib was not in my tensorflowenvironment, so I went

```
conda install matplotlib
```

I'm still afraid something is wrong with my conda tensorflow environment, shouldn't the matplotlib have been in there by default? It also told me:

```
Package plan for installation in environment /home/leon/.conda/envs/tensorflow:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

cycler:           0.10.0-py35_0    
dbus:             1.10.10-0        
expat:            2.1.0-0          
fontconfig:       2.12.1-3         
freetype:         2.5.5-2          
glib:             2.50.2-1         
gst-plugins-base: 1.8.0-0          
gstreamer:        1.8.0-0          
icu:              54.1-0           
jpeg:             9b-0             
libffi:           3.2.1-1          
libgcc:           5.2.0-0          
libiconv:         1.14-0           
libpng:           1.6.27-0         
libxcb:           1.12-1           
libxml2:          2.9.4-0          
matplotlib:       2.0.0-np112py35_0
mkl:              2017.0.1-0       
numpy:            1.12.0-py35_0    
pcre:             8.39-1           
pyparsing:        2.1.4-py35_0     
pyqt:             5.6.0-py35_2     
python-dateutil:  2.6.0-py35_0     
pytz:             2016.10-py35_0   
qt:               5.6.2-3          
sip:              4.18-py35_0      
six:              1.10.0-py35_0    

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

Which tells me also numpy was missing? Can someone confirm this to be correct now, or is there something fishy with my conda?

Comment: To be clear, since the answer isn't totally explicit, this is the expected behavior and absolutely nothing is wrong with your environment or conda.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just created a conda environment named tensorflow and switched into it.  You haven't installed the tensorflow package or any of the default anaconda packages.

To do that, do

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 anaconda # install anaconda3 default packages
source activate tensorflow # switch into it
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow # install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem using these instructions:
https://www.anaconda.com/tensorflow-in-anaconda/
for tensorflow-gpu.

Running

```
conda create -n tensorflow_gpuenv tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tensorflow_gpuenv
```

should ensure that "TensorFlow is now installed and ready for use."
But it doesn't.  Running 'conda list' shows matplotlib was not installed.  So you'll need to install that as well:

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on my mac.
So I ran conda list to see whether the matplotlib is installed or not.
Once i found it missing, i went ahead and ran the command `conda install matplotlib`.
After this step to verify it's properly installed; Do the following.

```
conda activate tf
```

This activates the tensorflow environment on anaconda.
After this start interactive python shell on the same terminal.

```
import matplotlib
```

If its installed properly this should not throw any error now.